# unable to read data from more than 1 row

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem reading data from the table. This is the sample of my coding

```
Dim SqlQry As String = "SELECT Distinct(RechargeAmt) from KioskItem where TelcoID='" & TelcoID & "'"
        Dim SqlCmd As New SqlCommand(SqlQry, Conn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read()
                Dim SqlQry As String = "SELECT Distinct(RechargeAmt) from KioskItem where TelcoID='" & TelcoID & "'"
        Dim SqlCmd As New SqlCommand(SqlQry, Conn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read()
                RechargeAmt = dr(0)
                a = a & RechargeAmt & ";"
            End While
        End If
        If a = 0 Then
            Return RechargeAmt
        Else
            Return a
        End If
```

My problem is if the data has more than one row, it has no problem saving the data into a string but when my data in the table has only one rowm, it is unable to read the data. i try this

```
If dr.HasRows Then
            RechargeAmt = dr(0)
            While dr.Read()
                a = a & RechargeAmt & ";"
            End While
        End If
        If a = 0 Then
            Return RechargeAmt
        Else
            Return a
        End If
```

but it still unable to read the data from the table

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are always missing the first row.

See here

```
 dr.Read()               //Gets the first row
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()  //Gets the second row onwards
```

You are always skipping the first row.

The initial read is not required. You could start directly with

```
 While dr.Read()
```

Control would go inside the loop only if there were rows.